# unable to install pusher because of Laravel Talk

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I wanted to install pusher using this command `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server` so i can make notifications of new messages from Laravel Talk but i get this error whenever i try to install pusher
[image]

Comment: You're using a package that is using other version of pusher, try to install a version it supports, `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:2.6.1`

Comment: Thank you so much this really solved my problem .. could you please let me know how did you know the meaning of this error and how did you manage to find another version of pusher so can i handle just issue in the future by myself .. sorry i am a bit new to laravel